# Trying to use Agora for Flutter and there seems to be some problem with version

Tags: flutter, android-studio, webrtc, version, agora.io

I am trying to add video calling feature to my app and I am using Agora for it. But when I do the build I get the following error:

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
D:\Downloads\flutter_windows_2.5.1-stable\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\ma
in\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionManager.java:321: error: cannot find symbol
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
^
symbol:   variable S
location: class VERSION_CODES
D:\Downloads\flutter_windows_2.5.1-stable\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\ma
in\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionUtils.java:72: error: cannot find symbol
case Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN:
^
symbol:   variable BLUETOOTH_SCAN
location: class permission
D:\Downloads\flutter_windows_2.5.1-stable\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\ma
in\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionUtils.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
case Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE:
^
symbol:   variable BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE
location: class permission
D:\Downloads\flutter_windows_2.5.1-stable\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\ma
in\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionUtils.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
case Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT:
^
symbol:   variable BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
location: class permission
D:\Downloads\flutter_windows_2.5.1-stable\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\ma
in\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionUtils.java:259: error: cannot find symbol
String result = determineBluetoothPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN);
^
symbol:   variable BLUETOOTH_SCAN
location: class permission
D:\Downloads\flutter_windows_2.5.1-stable\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\ma
in\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionUtils.java:270: error: cannot find symbol
String result = determineBluetoothPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE);
^
symbol:   variable BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE
location: class permission
D:\Downloads\flutter_windows_2.5.1-stable\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\ma
in\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionUtils.java:281: error: cannot find symbol
String result = determineBluetoothPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT);
^
symbol:   variable BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
location: class permission
D:\Downloads\flutter_windows_2.5.1-stable\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\ma
in\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionUtils.java:370: error: cannot find symbol
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S && hasPermissionInManifest(context, null, permission )) {
^
symbol:   variable S
location: class VERSION_CODES
8 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':permission_handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

**This is my pubspec.yaml:**

```
dependencies:
  #videocall
  agora_rtc_engine: ^4.0.7
  permission_handler: null
```

**This is AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- The Agora SDK requires Bluetooth permissions in case users are using Bluetooth devices.-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

**This is app\build.gradle:**

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "**********"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Comment: This seems to be issue of `permission_handler` instead of `agora_rtc_engine` .  if using `permission_handler` version 8.2.0 or grater you need to set  compileSdkVersion to value 31. You can read more about it - [setup permission handler](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/blob/master/permission_handler/README.md)